# How to directly access usb mass storage in Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am making specific my usb device. 
This device shall use on Android phone. This one use mass storage protocol. but this one is not mass storage device. This one have not FAT file system. It's only use mass storage protocol. This device is not mounted. Only present "/dev/block/vold/8:0" on root file system in android phone. I try access "/dev/block/vold/8:0" device file. device's open operation was success.
but can't read data from my usb device in Android NDK .
I want to use follow.
int vnHandle
vnHandle = open("/dev/sdc1", "rw")
read(vnHandle, buffer, readSize)
write(vnHandle, buffer, writeSize)

I already read/write my usb device in WindowsXP/7 by Visual Sutido 2010(dll). All is OK. but On Android NDK fail, is impossible? help me.

Comment: Android doesn't normally ship with a block storage driver that knowns about USB mass storage peripherals.  Apps often end up talking the mass storage protocol themselves, in userspace, working against the Android USB APIs.

Comment: thank you. this is no proper answer.

Comment: Indeed, it was not posted as an answer, but rather as a comment raising some ideas you may want to research.

Comment: thank you. see you again

Answer (score 0):

- Register intent-filter for [USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html#ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)

  - Include filter for vendor-id and/or product-id to match your specific usb device
- When USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED notification is received your code must request permission to access the device using [UsbManager#requestPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html#requestPermission(android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice,%20android.app.PendingIntent))
- Now you have the [UsbDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html).
- Open [UsbDeviceConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html). Because its a specific USB device you'll have to make your own calls to [controlTransfer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#controlTransfer(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20byte[],%20int,%20int,%20int)) and [bulkTransfer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#bulkTransfer(android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint,%20byte[],%20int,%20int,%20int)).